# Debugging previously debugged line in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

In dotnet there is an option set next statement to debug previously debugged line, similarly is there any option in eclipse so that we can debug the statement instead of running the whole application again

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse "Debug" view,, there is the "Drop To Frame" context menu entry. It lets you restart a method call from your current stack trace, not the individual statement inside a method.

Of course, it doesn't undo effects on state outside the call stack and the local variables there, but I guess dotnet can't do that as well.

Comment: Drop to frame is always in a disabled state.

Comment: If so, I suggest you share a picture of your editor setting a breakpoint and showing the disabled "drop to frame" icon. That may provide other visible clues.